# Xcode macOS "NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 You don’t have permission to save the file.." in Platform "App" but not in platform "command line tool"

Tags: xcode, macos

My first macOS Xcode program.

```
I want to save the srting str.
```

This error comes in the platform "macOS" with Application "App" but nor in "playground" and not in

the platform "macOS" with Application "command line tool"

Where is the bug???

```
let fileUrl = URL(filePath: "/Users/xxxx/documents/H02CCDate/H20Files/Tbl1/tbl01.txt")
if(try? fileUrl.checkResourceIsReachable()) == true {
            print("Datei/Verzeichnis existiert")
        } else {
            print("existiert nicht")
        }
        
        let str = "Super long string here"
        
        do {
            try str.write(to: fileUrl, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("03")
            print(str)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            print("nicht geschrieben")
            fatalError("FatalError-Meldung.Tbl1 fehlt")
        }
    }
//printoutput: "Datei/Verzeichnis existiert"
//printoutput: "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “tbl01.txt” in the folder “Tbl1”."
etc.
```

I tried the same code in all Applications without success.
Only with playground and command line tool  I was successful.

Comment: The error occurs if the sandbox is enabled because you can only access the Documents directory of the application **container**.

Comment: And you need to sign the exec with the entitlement that gives it permission to operate where you are asking.